# Copy a range from one workbook and pasting to a sheet another VBA

Tags: excel, vba, copy, paste

I am running a code using VBA. It starts by looping through a directory and pulling the files.

My goal is to copy a range and paste it to a template worksheet.

The copy code looks like such:

```
Dim StrFile As Variant
For Each StrFile In var

Workbooks.Open (loc1 & StrFile)

    sh.Activate
    On Error Resume Next
    Set uBOM = Cells.Find(What:="No.", After:=[A1], LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
    LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
    MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
    Range(Cells(uCost.Row + 1, uCost.Column), Cells(uCost.Row.End(xlDown), uCost.Columnn + 4)).Copy
    On Error GoTo 0

Next StrFile
```

How can I modify this or use to paste this into the template workbook (which I will be running the code from)?

Regards,
Marc